# To get Dictionary value from Array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to extract Temperature value from his array of dictionaries data for both F and C and set on text label, I am getting this data from acuweather API, Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks 
[
  {
    "LocalObservationDateTime": "2017-08-28T11:06:00-07:00",
    "EpochTime": 1503943560,
    "WeatherText": "Sunny",
    "WeatherIcon": 1,
    "IsDayTime": true,
    "Temperature": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 29.4,
        "Unit": "C",
        "UnitType": 17
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 85,
        "Unit": "F",
        "UnitType": 18
      }
    },
    "RealFeelTemperature": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 34.6,
        "Unit": "C",
        "UnitType": 17
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 94,
        "Unit": "F",
        "UnitType": 18
      }
    },
    "RealFeelTemperatureShade": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 29.4,
        "Unit": "C",
        "UnitType": 17
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 85,
        "Unit": "F",
        "UnitType": 18
      }
    },
    "RelativeHumidity": 35,
    "DewPoint": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 12.8,
        "Unit": "C",
        "UnitType": 17
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 55,
        "Unit": "F",
        "UnitType": 18
      }
    },
    "Wind": {
      "Direction": {
        "Degrees": 0,
        "Localized": "N",
        "English": "N"
      },
      "Speed": {
        "Metric": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "km/h",
          "UnitType": 7
        },
        "Imperial": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "mi/h",
          "UnitType": 9
        }
      }
    },
    "WindGust": {
      "Speed": {
        "Metric": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "km/h",
          "UnitType": 7
        },
        "Imperial": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "mi/h",
          "UnitType": 9
        }
      }
    },
    "UVIndex": 7,
    "UVIndexText": "High",
    "Visibility": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 16.1,
        "Unit": "km",
        "UnitType": 6
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 10,
        "Unit": "mi",
        "UnitType": 2
      }
    },
    "ObstructionsToVisibility": "",
    "CloudCover": 0,
    "Ceiling": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 10058,
        "Unit": "m",
        "UnitType": 5
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 33000,
        "Unit": "ft",
        "UnitType": 0
      }
    },
    "Pressure": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 1010.2,
        "Unit": "mb",
        "UnitType": 14
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 29.83,
        "Unit": "inHg",
        "UnitType": 12
      }
    },
    "PressureTendency": {
      "LocalizedText": "Falling",
      "Code": "F"
    },
    "Past24HourTemperatureDeparture": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": -1.1,
        "Unit": "C",
        "UnitType": 17
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": -2,
        "Unit": "F",
        "UnitType": 18
      }
    },
    "ApparentTemperature": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 28.9,
        "Unit": "C",
        "UnitType": 17
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 84,
        "Unit": "F",
        "UnitType": 18
      }
    },
    "WindChillTemperature": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 29.4,
        "Unit": "C",
        "UnitType": 17
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 85,
        "Unit": "F",
        "UnitType": 18
      }
    },
    "WetBulbTemperature": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 18.7,
        "Unit": "C",
        "UnitType": 17
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 66,
        "Unit": "F",
        "UnitType": 18
      }
    },
    "Precip1hr": {
      "Metric": {
        "Value": 0,
        "Unit": "mm",
        "UnitType": 3
      },
      "Imperial": {
        "Value": 0,
        "Unit": "in",
        "UnitType": 1
      }
    },
    "PrecipitationSummary": {
      "Precipitation": {
        "Metric": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "mm",
          "UnitType": 3
        },
        "Imperial": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "in",
          "UnitType": 1
        }
      },
      "PastHour": {
        "Metric": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "mm",
          "UnitType": 3
        },
        "Imperial": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "in",
          "UnitType": 1
        }
      },
      "Past3Hours": {
        "Metric": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "mm",
          "UnitType": 3
        },
        "Imperial": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "in",
          "UnitType": 1
        }
      },
      "Past6Hours": {
        "Metric": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "mm",
          "UnitType": 3
        },
        "Imperial": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "in",
          "UnitType": 1
        }
      },
      "Past9Hours": {
        "Metric": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "mm",
          "UnitType": 3
        },
        "Imperial": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "in",
          "UnitType": 1
        }
      },
      "Past12Hours": {
        "Metric": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "mm",
          "UnitType": 3
        },
        "Imperial": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "in",
          "UnitType": 1
        }
      },
      "Past18Hours": {
        "Metric": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "mm",
          "UnitType": 3
        },
        "Imperial": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "in",
          "UnitType": 1
        }
      },
      "Past24Hours": {
        "Metric": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "mm",
          "UnitType": 3
        },
        "Imperial": {
          "Value": 0,
          "Unit": "in",
          "UnitType": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "TemperatureSummary": {
      "Past6HourRange": {
        "Minimum": {
          "Metric": {
            "Value": 18.3,
            "Unit": "C",
            "UnitType": 17
          },
          "Imperial": {
            "Value": 65,
            "Unit": "F",
            "UnitType": 18
          }
        },
        "Maximum": {
          "Metric": {
            "Value": 30,
            "Unit": "C",
            "UnitType": 17
          },
          "Imperial": {
            "Value": 86,
            "Unit": "F",
            "UnitType": 18
          }
        }
      },
      "Past12HourRange": {
        "Minimum": {
          "Metric": {
            "Value": 18.3,
            "Unit": "C",
            "UnitType": 17
          },
          "Imperial": {
            "Value": 65,
            "Unit": "F",
            "UnitType": 18
          }
        },
        "Maximum": {
          "Metric": {
            "Value": 30,
            "Unit": "C",
            "UnitType": 17
          },
          "Imperial": {
            "Value": 86,
            "Unit": "F",
            "UnitType": 18
          }
        }
      },
      "Past24HourRange": {
        "Minimum": {
          "Metric": {
            "Value": 18.3,
            "Unit": "C",
            "UnitType": 17
          },
          "Imperial": {
            "Value": 65,
            "Unit": "F",
            "UnitType": 18
          }
        },
        "Maximum": {
          "Metric": {
            "Value": 41.7,
            "Unit": "C",
            "UnitType": 17
          },
          "Imperial": {
            "Value": 107,
            "Unit": "F",
            "UnitType": 18
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "MobileLink": "http://m.accuweather.com/en/us/dublin-ca/94568/current-weather/332106?lang=en-us",
    "Link": "http://www.accuweather.com/en/us/dublin-ca/94568/current-weather/332106?lang=en-us"
  }
]

Comment: What format do you want the result in?

Comment: So your data starts with a '[' and ends with a '}'?  It looks broken to me.

Comment: Now I have mentioned full data please do share how to find temperature in c and f both

Comment: We are not a code writing service. Show us your code and and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: this is simple json data I am getting which is dictionaries of an array only I need to find Temperature value in c and f both. which I must store in String so if you can help please suggest me, sorry I am new to Swift learning

Comment: You will continue to be new to Swift learning if you keep asking us to write your code for you. Read a tutorial and make an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonSerialisation [jsonObjectWithData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization/1415493-jsonobjectwithdata?language=objc) to convert jSon response to NSArray object. And then access the [0] index of the array as NSDictionary and then take 'Temperature' values.

To know more about accessing values from NSDictionary, [apple docs reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary)

To know more about working with json in swift, [apple docs reference](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37).

Answer (score -2):

It's not totally clear what you are asking.  The data isn't in Swift format, so it may be the question of how to parse the data.  Even if we substitute { for [, they don't match up. 
If the question is about dictionary handling then you need to drill down from dictionary to dictionary:

```
let dict = [
  "LocalObservationDateTime": "2017-08-27T13:25:00-07:00", 
  "EpochTime": 1503865500, 
  "WeatherText": "Sunny", 
  "WeatherIcon": 1, 
  "IsDayTime": true, 
  "Temperature": [ 
    "Metric": [ 
      "Value": 37.8, 
      "Unit": "C", 
      "UnitType": 17 
    ], 
    "Imperial": [ 
      "Value": 100, 
      "Unit": "F", 
      "UnitType": 18 
    ] 
  ], 
  "RealFeelTemperature": [ 
    "Metric": [ 
      "Value": 43.1, 
      "Unit": "C", 
      "UnitType": 17 
    ], 
    "Imperial": [ 
      "Value": 110, 
      "Unit": "F", 
      "UnitType": 18 
    ] 
  ], 
  "RealFeelTemperatureShade": [ 
    "Metric": [ 
      "Value": 37.8, 
      "Unit": "C", 
      "UnitType": 17 
    ], 
    "Imperial": [ 
      "Value": 100, 
      "Unit": "F", 
      "UnitType": 18 
    ] 
  ], 
  "RelativeHumidity": 16 
] as [String : Any]

let temp = dict["Temperature"] as! [String: Any]
let metric = temp["Metric"] as! [String: Any]
let value = metric["Value"] as! Double
print(value)
```

Comment: What is shown by OP is a JSON string! Of course it's not in Swift syntax. Do NOT, never, transform the characters of a JSON string like that. Instead, use JSONSerialization to decode the JSON.